# Get yesterday's rows startign from 10AM

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

For previous day I used use the below expression .

```
     DATE_INSERTED >=DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0) 
     AND  DATE_INSERTED < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

How to get rows from yesterday 10Am to today 10AM

Comment: I suggest using `DATEADD` instead of shorthand like `-1` - this won't work with new types like `DATE`. `DATEADD` is more work to write but it allows your code to be consistent and compatible with all types.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- yesterday at midnight:
DECLARE @yesterday DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0);

SELECT
...
WHERE DATE_INSERTED >= DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @yesterday)  -- 10 AM yesterday
  AND DATE_INSERTED <  DATEADD(HOUR, 34, @yesterday); -- 10 AM today
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using zeroes, use some date(time)s that have the desirable properties:

```
DATE_INSERTED >=
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'20010102',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T10:00:00') 
 AND  DATE_INSERTED <
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'20010102',GETDATE()),'2001-01-02T10:00:00')
```

I.e. if you add the total number of days that have occurred since 2nd January 2001 onto 10:00am on the 1st January 2001, you'll always obtain a value which is "yesterday at 10am". The second one is almost identical.