# Convert nvarchar to date in query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have date value in a string as below how can I query against date.
This is how I need to query the evtdate is nvarchar and has date value like this
2013-07-18 06:30:30.843000000

```
Declare @yesterday datetime - dateadd(day,diff(day,1,getdate(),0)
select count(*) from tbl1
where evtdate >= dateadd(hour,10,@yesterday)
```

OR

```
select count(*) from tbl1
where evtdate >- dateadd(day,'20010102',getdate()-2),'2001-01-01T10:00:00')
```

Comment: Why, why, why is evtdate nvarchar? Also, how is this question different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105986/get-yesterdays-rows-startign-from-10am), except there you didn't bother telling us the column was nvarchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105986/get-yesterdays-rows-startign-from-10am) you want to count the rows in a 24-hour period, starting from 10 AM yesterday, up to (but not including) 10 AM today.

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, evtdate) >= DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @yesterday)
  AND CONVERT(DATETIME, evtdate) <  DATEADD(HOUR, 34, @yesterday);
```

I strongly recommend you change `evtdate` from `nvarchar` to `datetime` (and consider indexing it if this query pattern is common). That column has absolutely no business whatsoever being `nvarchar` - `varchar` would be bad enough, but with `nvarchar` not only are you losing built-in validation and date/time methods, you're storing two bytes for every character, even though a `datetime` will never have any characters that require Unicode. And how do you currently prevent someone from storing `'floob'` or `'Jimmy Hoffa'` in that column?

Comment: Thanks, Aaron for the suggestions.At that time the data is being imported from transactional to Reporting databases and didn't find any issues but now the data is being loaded from a file and table column type is nvarchar.I will try to modify the column datatype.Again thanks for all the valuable suggestions.